# New Items are not added to the source control

Tags: c#, tfs

I need to add new pages to project which is in source control. I add them from visual studio, but the source control doesn't locate them as new and on check in they are not placed in the TFS. This is valid for every item: images, pages ...

**Should I change some setting or what, why this happen.**

Comment: have you checked your TFS bindings in visual studio? File -> Source control -> advance -> change source control should open a window where you can see the server bindings.

Comment: @Jay thanks man, the project was not binded to the tfs for some reason. I don't know how this was working in the past ! Add it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: no probs. glad i could help. Added my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your TFS bindings in visual studio.

File -> Source control -> advance -> change source control

this should open a window where you can see the server bindings.